# JSON.parse: unexpected character -- Syntax is correct, data type is string

Tags: javascript, json

I am completely baffled. I am getting an exception when trying to `JSON.parse()` the following string:

```
{"result":0,"extra":"2a9e10ecdeb8e65165c8635d51fd6b8f6fa7c10e951167a093ac1621e81dd7e8"}
```

The exact error reported by the exception is:

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

The string syntax is correct according to JSONLint. I have also confirmed that the data type is string.

What could be causing the exception?

Comment: If the thing you're passing `JSON.parse` is really a string, and those are really its contents, you will not get that error. (Unless you've replaced `JSON.parse` with something nonstandard, which you probably haven't.) Update the question with a [mcve] that we can actually see demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the input to `JSON.parse` is a `string` and not a JSON Object?

Comment: Hey your input is  object that is why your getting error

Comment: @KarthikVU Please do not perpetuate the confusing and incorrect usage "JSON Object". In any case, he already said that it **is** a string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to quote the string?

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('{"result":0,"extra":"2a9e10ecdeb8e65165c8635d51fd6b8f6fa7c10e951167a093ac1621e81dd7e8"}'))
```

Omitting the quotes would yield an object literal:

```js
console.log({"result":0,"extra":"2a9e10ecdeb8e65165c8635d51fd6b8f6fa7c10e951167a093ac1621e81dd7e8"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably assigning that value literally, wich is an object not a string, so:

```
var invalidJSON = {"result":0,"extra":"2a9e10ecdeb8e65165c8635d51fd6b8f6fa7c10e951167a093ac1621e81dd7e8"};

var validJSON = '{"result":0,"extra":"2a9e10ecdeb8e65165c8635d51fd6b8f6fa7c10e951167a093ac1621e81dd7e8"}';
```